# Can you have a trash bin in shul?

Tags: halacha, synagogue, kavod, disposal

Over Shabbos, the Shul in which I davened had a trash bin towards the back.  This caused me to realize that I do not think that I have ever seen another permanent Shul sanctuary which had a garbage can in it.  I also don't remember seeing a Yeshiva Beis Medrash with a garbage can in it.

I can hear how maybe it would be disrespectful to have a garbage bin in a Shul or Beis Medrash, but it's pretty convenient.  Is there any *halachic* calculation involved in this?  Was the Shul that I saw had a garbage can in violation of anything, and do they have something to rely on?

Comment: Not sure about the kavod tag.

Comment: The orthodox shul that I daven at has a small wastebasket to the left of the aron.  I was a little surprised when I first saw it up at the front, but it is useful for Kleenexes . . .

Comment: I think most Beis Medrashes I've been to did have garbage cans in them so YMMV.

Comment: Do you mean in the building at all, or just in the davening/study area?  I've definitely seen them in entry halls and stuff like that.

Comment: @MonicaCellio in the sanctuary itself.

Comment: @DoubleAA I guess it could vary.  Ner Israel, KBY, the Lakewood batei midrashim in which I have been, and the Mir beis medrash that I was in did not.  I can think of several others that didn't.  But either how, I've been in many more shuls and TTBOMK never seen one.

Comment: I daven in a beis midrash/shul that has at least three garbage cans inside the beis midrash.

Comment: I think that halachically, the problem is davening next to a bad smell. So, my thinking - people rarely (and shouldn't) be eating in a shul, so no need for a trash can. I've never seen one in shul. Bet Midrash - people eat (maybe more than they should!) You don't want a mess of food stuff etc. all over, so I have seen plenty of trash cans in the Bet Midrash. Hopefully, someone empties it out often enough before it stinks, so even if you daven there, it should not be a halachic concern.

Comment: My shul shares space with a pre school and we have a few garbage cans around.

Comment: Almost every shul I've been in has had garbage cans for tissues and stuff in it. I don't recall what was in most *batei midrash* I've been in, but there certainly have been a few that have had them.

Comment: Gateshead Yeshiva Govoha contains bins all round the Beis.

Comment: @Shokhet really?  I'm surprised by that.  Every shul in Baltimore that I can think of (that I was in) did not.  Every shul in the town I live in now (that I've been in) does not.  Every shul in the town I grew up in (that I've been in) did not.  Are you talking about anywhere in the building, or in the actual sanctuary?  Because I am referring to the latter.

Comment: I was referring to the latter also.

Comment: @Shokhet If I knew how to make a shocked emoticon, I'd be doing so now.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm ... pretty much as I suspected and said n my comment. See [here](http://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue17.pdf) and refer to reference #31.

> One should not throw garbage such as candy wrappers or tissues on the
>   floor of a shul. There is an uncertainty if one has to pick up garbage
>   that he sees on the floor of the shul. It would seem that the right
>   thing to do is to pick up the garbage from the shul’s floor. One
>   should keep the garbage cans outside of the shul.

Source there says:

> Opinion of Horav Chaim Kanievsky Shlita quoted in Bais Yehuda
>   16:12:footnote 7. It is permitted to place mice traps in a shul (Bais
>   Yehuda 16:8:footnote 13 quoting the opinion of Horav Chaim Kanievesky
>   Shlita).

The ending has me wondering, though. If you catch the mouse and you're davening with a dead mouse in the trap .... isn't that a problem?

Comment: I think it's a problem only if it smells, or if you touch it; CYLOR.

Comment: @Shokhet - I'm inclined to agree, but seeing a dead mouse is gross. Of course, I guess it's far worse than having a live one running around the shul ... unless it's wearing a kippah :-) Of course, it could be a Muslim in disguise and someone could say "Alahu Akhbar" :-) :-)